# How to downgrade from M2 to M0 mongoDB Cluster Tier

Tags: mongodb-atlas

I have M2 Mongodb cluster and wanted to downgrade to M0.  When I go to modify it only allows for upgrades.  Is there another way to downgrade to free tier?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't just downgrade to free tier like that.  You might try exporting the data, creating a new free tier cluster an importing.

Comment: @Josh were you able to do it?

Answer (score 18):

You can't scale down to am M0 as the free tier uses a different shared architecture to the other clusters. However you can dump your data using [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) and restore using [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) to an M0 cluster as long as it doesn't exceed the constraints of the cluster.