# MongoAtlas Downgrade Cluster tiers Consequences and Tips

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am in charge of a web application that is using a MongoDB Atlas Replica Cluster tier M20. I monitored last 2 months and it is definitely oversized with a peak of 12/100 IOPS and 55/3000 connections. Furthermore, I am sure that the amount of users is not going to increase in a while.
Therefore, I want to know if Anyone has **downgraded** a MongoDB Altras Cluster **tier** and if there are any consequences or problems that I have to take into account? I want to pass it to M10.

In the documentation, they talk about "initial sync". It is done automatically? or I have to do it?

Someone published a similar question, but no one answered:
[How to downgrade from M2 to M0 mongoDB Cluster Tier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62156731/how-to-downgrade-from-m2-to-m0-mongodb-cluster-tier)

Answer (score 2):

M20 to M10 is straightforward. Just change the config and Atlas will do the rest. No consequences other than lower performance. We have a cluster than scales up and down between an M10 and and M20 at least once a week.